# is Uniqueidentifier datatype with primary key supported in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to Hive and facing some problems when 
I am trying for importing the table from SQL into Hive.

In SQL I have the table in which one of the field is primary key having datatype "UiqueIdentifier"

While importing in Hive   the sqoop applies uses this as :
(console log) : `INFO db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat: BoundingValsQuery: SELECT MIN([addressuid]), MAX([addressuid]) FROM [Address]`

Hence it give the error as :

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:
Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for min operator.
```

My question is that Does Hive support uniqueidentifier with primary key?

How should I solve this problem?
Pls suggest me some solution.

Comment: Suggestion: Accept answers for some of your previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1073129/user1073129?tab=questions  It will make it more likely that someone will answer this one.

Answer (score 0):

sqoop can't divide up the work for map/reducing on a column with datatype uniqueIdentifier and by default it uses the primary key for this. Either use --num-mappers 1 so that there is no need for sqoop to divide up the work or use --split-by with a date or numeric column to override the default.